# What VI syntax colours does Cygwin use

Tags: vim, vi

I've just uninstalled Cygwin because it wasn't working for the purpose i wanted so I installed GIT Bash but the syntax is different for .py files whilst editing with VI i was just wondering if anyone knew what to do to get the same colour scheme with VI?

Comment: Maybe you can try on http://vi.stackexchange.com/ `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the colors in GIT Bash by right clicking the bar at the top of the window, selecting options, and looking under "Looks". You can do the same with Cygwin. You may also want to consider using GVIM, which is more configurable as far as appearance goes than Cygwin or GIT Bash are.